# Negating a variable shortcut

Tags: c#

This maybe a trivial question but I couldn't find it so easily.

There are some shortcuts like

```
i = i + 1;
i++;

i = i+20;
i += 20;
```

But is there something to negate in place a variable?

```
MyClass.MyVeryLongSubClass.MoreStuff.MyBooleanHere = !MyClass.MyVeryLongSubClass.MoreStuff.MyBooleanHere;
```

Comment: Generally if you're having to reach out across several objects to reach your target variable, then there's something wrong with your design.

Comment: I assume the emphasis is on a `bool` variable? The text is not very clear about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
x ^= true;
```

It's a bit obscure though, which is why people generally don't use that.

Comment: What meaning could have x ^= false; ?

Comment: `x ^= false` would be a no-op (no change to `x`).

Comment: I like this one, it never occurred to me to try it.

Answer (score 0):

A purely numeric (and not obscure) solution would be:

```
x *= -1;
```

---

**UPDATE**

Note also that the assignment operation yields a value and can be used within an expression.

instead of

```
x = -x;
y = 100 * x;
```

you can write

```
y = 100 * (x = -x);
```

or even

```
y = 100 * (x *= -1);
```

But I prefer the first version. The second and third are not easily understandable.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Yes, but it will work for floating- and fixed-point numbers.